# Compile shell script to make it totally unreadable

Tags: bash, shell, unix, debian

I need to compile my shell script, because I want to protect its source code. I already read about `shc`, but I also read, that it isn't completely safe, because with a small amount of knowledge (or brain and google) any user can 'decompile' it. Is there a way to compile my script to make it executable, but completely unreadable and 'undecompileable'?

Comment: No. Think about it, bash has to be able to read it enough to make sense of it and run it, if bash can do it, so can a human (probably using the debug facilities built into bash). There are things you can do to obfuscate the code, but at most that will slow someone down.

Comment: _because with a small amount of knowledge (or brain and google) any user can *'decompile'* it._ an small amount of knowledge... for understanding decompiled C code?

Comment: We could debate the meaning of small/medium/large amount of knowledge forever, but the fact is, it's not that hard to disassemble/decompile code and figure out what it's doing. It's certainly not so hard that anyone should rely on its difficulty to protect IP, or whatever the poster's trying to protect.

Comment: So regardless of compiling, obfuscate, etc. the only way to protect it is to encrypt it with openssl or something, and make script unexecutable and unreadable for bash? So compiling it with `shc` is the best available way to protect my source code and keep it executable?

Comment: Yes, there is a way: rewrite it in a language that allows this. How big is the script? What does it do?

Comment: Obfuscation is a very bad way to secure things. BTW, what do you mean by 'protect' the source code? do you want to dissimulate some important things (like your bank account number) or do you wan to protect it from modifications (make sure it is not corrupted when executing)?

Comment: This is not compiling. You're looking for a minifier/obfuscator, which I won't recommend. Obfuscation *introduces bugs*, because obfuscators themselves are software and hence have bugs. Why add another venue for introducing bugs, when it's already hard enough to write robust code? Besides, do you really need to be so protective of your shell script? If you're written a 10k–100k line project in shell, you're probably choosing the wrong language; shell scripts are usually fairly short.

Comment: You can simply use Perl. It's unreadable by design.

Comment: Before bothering with this, you should run `strace` to see how much info you would inevitably leak through invoking external programs. Most shell scripts are 99.99% external programs and 0.01% actual sh.

Comment: When your code is so good worth stealing, it is worth buying including support as well. Good code is promotion for yourself. Or do you want to make bad code unreadable? Really, reconsider your motivation.

Answer (score 1):

You can only make it harder to read by a human being. Scripts are plain text files, they have to be readable by the script interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

I made my own bash obfuscator (obash) in a way that the keys required to extract the script are not stored inside the script (but that makes the script non distributable). There is an option to generate static reusable binary but that will only execute on systems that have several levels of compatibility (kernel system call interface, glibc, basic binary compatibility).
Making the re-distributable binary also implies storing a key in the generated binary but the stored keys need to be manipulated before use.
You might like to try and see if obash serves you any better then shc.

Answer (score 0):

I developed [shellc](https://github.com/chenzhch/shellc), which can convert shell scripts into C code. One of the obfuscation mechanisms is to create a pipe to an interactive shell and feed decrypted commands into the pipe. Shellc also has certain debugging prevention capabilities.

Comment: What does `pipe bash` mean?

Comment: For example:FILE *pipe=popen(getenv("SHELL"),"w"); puts("echo 'aa', pipe);

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).